# Scraping a list of sites with PhantomJS through Selenium freezes on AWS, but works locally

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, phantomjs

I'm writing a scraping code using selenium and PhantomJS. It works perfectly on local machine but as i run the code from AWS it works for a while and freezes all of a sudden.

Here is my code :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import csv
import re
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait


class DukeSpider(BaseSpider):
  name = "dspider"
  allowed_domains = ["dukemedicine.org"]
  start_urls = ["http://www.dukemedicine.org/find-doctors-physicians"]  #hlor


  def __init__(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args=['--ssl-protocol=any'])
    self.driver.maximize_window()
    print 'here'


  def parse(self, response):


    b = open('doc_data_duke.csv', 'a')
    a = csv.writer(b, lineterminator='\n')


    self.driver.get(response.url)
    time.sleep(10)
    wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)
            click = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@id='specialty']")
    click.click()
    click_again = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
        "//ul[@class='doctor-type']/li[@class='ng-binding ng-scope'][2]")

    click_again.click()
    time.sleep(15)

    act = ActionChains(self.driver)
    act.move_to_element(self.driver.find_element_by_id('doctor-matrix-section')).click()
    print 'now here'

    for i in range(0, 10):
        #self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='doctor-matrix-section']").send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)

        act.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN).perform()
        time.sleep(1)
        print 'hello'
        print i
        i += 1

    links = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class = 'result-information']/div[@class='name']/a")

    for l in links:
        print l
        doc_list = l.get_attribute('href')
        if re.match(r'https:\/\/www\.dukemedicine\.org\/find-doctors-physicians\/#!\/(.*)', doc_list):
            print doc_list
            dr = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args=['--ssl-protocol=any'])
            dr.maximize_window()

            dr.get(doc_list)  #This is where it freezes

            try:
                name_title = dr.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="header1 ng-binding"]').text
                name_titles = name_title.split(",", 1)
                name = name_titles[0].encode('utf-8')

                title = name_titles[1]
                print name.encode('utf-8')
                title = title[1:].encode('utf-8')
                print title.encode('utf-8')
            except:
                name = ''
                title = ''
```

The code works for some websites in the list but freezes all of a sudden.
Python version : 2.7.6
Selenium version : 2.47.3
PhantomJs version: 1.9.0

Comment: @ArtjomB.   i posted the version

Comment: That's quite an ancient PhantomJS version. You should try 2.0.0, 1.9.8, 1.9.7 (in that order).

Comment: Thanks a lot , it worked with 1.9.8